# Firestore and Mysql on Spring Boot. Is it possible?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with Spring Boot application. I want to connect a Firestore and a MySql database in my Spring boot application. I would to know if it is possible. So I'm wondering if someone have an easy example to know this magic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Connection itself shouldn't be any problem. Firestore has well developed API for all popular languages, very simple and convenient to use, please check reference bellow.

You have mentioned MySQL, not sure if you are aware that GCP has also serverless Cloud SQL that can run MySQL for you ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#mysql)).

You can find it here references and quick-starts here:

Google Cloud Firestore: [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers), [How-to](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/how-to) and [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/apis).

Here I found example app tutorial: [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEk0FETL6QE).

Other interesting stuff: [Spring Boot on GCP](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/databases/cloud-firestore), [Deploying on cloud](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/cloud-deployment.html#cloud-deployment-gae) from docs.spring.io.

You can also deploy your Spring Boot app on [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/quickstart) which can give you serverless solution for whole your stack - whole on GCP.

Comment: Thanks @vitooh . I have already a Spring application running with Firestore. My problem is to have a Spring JPA Relational DB and at the same time the Firestore logic. When I've tried to run together I got this error - org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Reactive Repositories are not supported by JPA

Comment: I suggest to create new question with  error stack and part of the code that is triggering the error. The best would be, if possible, to create simple code generating the exception like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example